# Ejb совместно c Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, ejb

Как в `spinge` использовать `EJB` классы.

Да `EJB` не очень, тем более в библиотеке использовать спринг или `ejb` - это жесть, но что досталось то приходится пока использовать.
Есть вопросы

1. Как спринг дружит с `EJB` с аннотациями типа `stateless, ejb`, и даже `ConcurrencyManagement`.
2. Если сервер приложений поднимает эти бины при запуске, как спринг делает их своими бинами и делает ли своими бинами или какая то прокся между бинами управляемые сервером приложений и бинами спринга
3. Как отключить поднятие `EJB` бинов сервером приложений и чтобы такие бины управлялись спрингом путем сканирования этих пакетов либо же просто через конфигурацию

Comment: вам же написали, что не хватает конструктора без параметров

Comment: да, но JMClient это класс из библиотеки, плюс к тому же там вообще нет конструкторов, значит там есть по умолчанию конструктор

Comment: тогда почему di контейнер считает что это бин?

Comment: @artem-konovalov Я не знаю, я всего лишь добавил его в зависимость, я еще не использовал ни один класс из этой либы

Comment: ну вообще то spring давно поддерживает jsr 330 и вполне может работать с аннотациями ejb. выключите сканирование бинов либо ограничте их только пакетами из своего проекта

Comment: @artem-konovalov Как она поддерживает, она создает те же бины?

Comment: @Inject как минимум будет работать

Comment: @artem-konovalov обновил вопрос

Comment: @artem-konovalov исключение пакета из сканирования спрингом не подходит, как я понял EJB бины поднимает не спринг а сервер приложений, как вот отключить поднятие этих бинов сервером приложений, в библиотеке в папке Meta-inf есть файл beans.xml

Comment: что у вас за application server?

Comment: @artem-konovalov IBM websphere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если коротко, только получать их от сервера приложений через JNDI.

Контейнер Spring и контейнер EJB/CDI - это два разных, хоть и похожих, мира. У бинов Spring и EJB разный жизненный цикл, а у контейнеров разные механизмы обеспечения этого жизненного цикла. Отсюда ответы на ваши вопросы:

1. Никак не дружит. Эти аннотации анализирует и действует в соответствии с ними CDI-контейнер.
2. Когда Spring встречает поле, в которое нужно внедрить зависимость, он ищет эту зависимость в контексте. А появиться зависимость в контексте может разными способами - в результате вызова конструктора объявленного в конфигурации бина, в результате вызова фабричного метода какого-нибудь класса, в результате JNDI-запроса. Как раз последним способом контекст Spring и получает EJB от сервера приложений.
3. Никак. Spring не сможет самостоятельно управлять EJB.

Так что вам придётся запустить ваше Spring-приложение, включающее EJB-компоненты, на сервере приложений, добавить в конфигурацию контекста что-нибудь вроде

```
<jee:local-slsb id="someEjb" jndi-name="ejb/someEJB"
        business-interface="com.example.SomeEJB"/>

<bean id="someSpringBean" class="com.example.SomeSpringBean">
    <property name="someEjb" ref="someEjb"/>
</bean>
```

и убедиться в наличии соответствующего сеттера в бине Spring

```
public class SomeSpringBean {
    private SomeEJB someEjb;

    public void setSomeEjb(SomeEJB someEjb) {
        this.someEjb = someEjb;
    }
}
```

Почитать можно [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#ejb-access).